# Braintree for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

I want to show the price of a plan I created in Braintree. I'm trying to retrieve the details via the the Braintree api by using this: `Braintree::Plan.price`

```
<%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
  <div id="dropin"></div>
  <%=submit_tag "Pay #{Braintree::Plan.price}$", class: "button mt1" %>
```

But I'm getting this error:
`undefined method price' for Braintree::Plan:Class`

Does someone know how to implement this?

Comment: Is price a class method?  It seems like you are calling an instance method on a class...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Eric!!! No it's not a class method.

Comment: You are calling an instance method on a class there... try calling it on an object... ex. `Braintree::Plan.last.price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... just had to put params["price"] into the submit tag!!

`<%=submit_tag "Pay #{params["price"]}$", class: "button mt1" %>`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to find the `Braintree::Subscription` by the `subscription_id` (if you have one) and then get price from there.

```
Braintree::Subscription.find("a_subscription_id").price
```

Or, you can search for `Braintree::Subscription` by a `plan_id` and then get the price.

```
Braintree::Subscription.search do |search|
  search.plan_id.is "the_plan_id"
end.first.price
```

Both of these examples are taken from [Braintree API Documentation for Subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/cancel/ruby)

It would be nice to retrieve a plan using something like: `Braintree::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)` and then get the price of the plan directly from there. But, unfortunately, I don't see that option in their [API Documentation for Plan](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/plan/all/ruby).

To get the price of the latest plan:

```
Braintree::Plan.last.price
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @K M Rakibul Islam... I'm trying to show the price inside the Braintree drop-in ui. Thus the subscription has not been created yet.

Comment: How many plans do you have right now? If you have just one plan, or if you wanna show the price of the latest created plan, then you can do: `Braintree::Plan.last.price`

Comment: Right now I only have 2. if I try `Braintree::Plan.last.price it returns  undefined method last' for Braintree::Plan:Class`

Comment: Also, not sure if would work, try this: `Braintree::Plan.find('plan_id')price`

Comment: Tried Braintree::Plan.find('plan_id')price and..... the `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting tSTRING_DEND ree::Plan.find('plan_id')price}$", class: "button mt1" );@ou ^`

Comment: there is a dor missing: `Braintree::Plan.find('plan_id').price`

Comment: Most probably its not gonna work. Seems like the API does not have that option to find a plan by its id.

Comment: yeap... `undefined method find' for Braintree::Plan:Class`

Comment: yeah, so for now, you have to go with one the options that I mentioned in my answer until we find a better way.